# Synchronization in the interrupr driven code (not RTOS)

Tags: microcontroller, race-condition

I stuck with the following problem.
let's suppose we have just a main-loop firmware without any RTOS.
We have a task to fill the buffer in some periodic interrupt handler (let it be the timer interrupt that performs ADC reading and puts that results to some buffer) and read from this buffer in the main loop.

```
#define BUF_LEN 10

uint16_t buffer[BUF_LEN];
int head = 0, tail = 0;

int next_ring_pos(int pos, int len) {
    return (pos + 1) % len;
}

void process_sample() {
    uint16_t sample_value;

    if (tail != head) {
        sample_value = buffer[tail];
        tail = next_ring_pos(tail, BUF_LEN);
        //do something with sample_value
    }
}

void put_sample(uint16_t sample_value) {
    if (tail != head) {
        buffer[head] = sample_value;
        head = next_ring_pos(head, BUF_LEN);
    } else {
        //do something if buffer overflow detected
    }
}
```

`put_sample` is periodically called from the timer's Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) and process_sample is periodically called in `main(1)` loop.
From my point of view we won't have any synchronization issues here since ISR changes only head pointer and main loop changes only tail pointer.
But i concern about this part: `if (tail != head)`.
Is it possible to have race condition here?
If yes then i have another question: are there any ways to synchronize interrupt code and low priority code (main loop)? We can't use any waiting primitives (like any condition variables and polling that with atomic operations) since we can't wait into ISR.

If race conditions are possible then i have another question: are there any ways to synchronize interrupt code and low priority code (main loop)? We can't use any waiting primitives (like any condition variables and polling that with atomic operations) since we can't wait into ISR.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely correct to be worried about things being modified in an ISR that can be used by the main loop. And you're also correct that since the ISR modifies `head` and the main loop modifies `tail`, this is somewhat safer.

However, using comparisons of `head` and `tail` to know if there is data (or space) in the buffer is very bug-prone. For example, if `head == tail`, is the buffer full or empty?

Much better is to explicitly keep track of how many items are in the queue, in a separate variable. Then this is the only variable that needs to be shared between the main loop and the ISR. It also makes deciding if there is data (or space) in the buffer trivial. This variable would need to be protected in the main loop when it is modified, to ensure the ISR doesn't get called during the read-write process. The simplest way to do that is to just disable interrupts during the modification.

If I was writing this, I'd do something like this:

```
#define BUF_LEN 10u

uint16_t buffer[BUF_LEN];
uint8_t head = 0u;                 // Where to insert
uint8_t tail = 0u;                 // Where to remove
volatile uint8_t num_entries = 0u; // How many entries

uint8_t next_ring_pos(uint8_t pos, uint8_t len)
{
    return (pos + 1u) % len;
}

void process_sample(void)
{
    uint16_t sample_value;

    if (mum_entries > 0u)
    {
        sample_value = buffer[tail];
        tail = next_ring_pos(tail, BUF_LEN);

        _disable_irq();
        -- num_entries;
        _enable_irq();
    
        //do something with sample_value
    }
    else
    {
        // Queue was empty
    }
}

void put_sample(uint16_t sample_value)
{
    if (num_entries < BUF_LEN)
    {
        buffer[head] = sample_value;
        head = next_ring_pos(head, BUF_LEN);

        ++ num_entries;
    }
    else
    {
        //do something if buffer overflow detected
    }
}
```

Note the `volatile` qualifier on `num_entries`. This is needed because the ISR might modify its value during the execution of `process_sample()`, so we need to ensure we are using the most recent value when we disable/enable interrupts.

If you absolutely don't want to disable interrupts, then you need to remove the ambiguity between empty and full queues. Simplest would be that `head == tail` is an empty queue, and `head == (tail - 1)` is a full queue. But we need to take the wrap-around (modulo) into account.

In that spirit, the original code could be made to work by changing the `put_sample()` function into something like this:

```
void put_sample(uint16_t sample_value) {
    int next_head = next_ring_pos(head, BUF_LEN);

    if (next_head != tail) {
        buffer[head] = sample_value;
        head = next_head;
    } else {
        //do something if buffer overflow detected
    }
}
```

I find this a bit obscure and harder to reason about, and it also means you can only store `BUF_LEN - 1` entries in the queue. But it might suit some requirements.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your solution. But I don't like to disable interrupts in real time systems since that can make some jitter for periodical interrupts. But in this particular case this interrupt disabling happens for the very short period and should not make significant jitter.   
Actually i wanted to use the ring buffer because i hoped that it can allow me to avoid disabling interrupts.

Comment: I don't know what microcontroller you are using, but on ARM Cortex-M for example, disabling (and enabling) interrupts is a single instruction. I don't think there is a quicker way. And yes, the critical section is very short. If it was longer, you might look at disabling just the one interrupt that inserts into the queue, rather than all interrupts.

Comment: I've added to my answer a way that does not require disabling interrupts. I don't prefer it, but maybe it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @pmacfarlane  
It's not a problem to reserve 1 item in array to avoid disabling interrupts.  
I think i need to try and test this approach.

Comment: Yes, i'm working with STM32 Cortex-M4 microcontroller. But actually this problem is common for any kind of firmware that uses interrupts and independent on microcontroller architecture.